# After removing .php and adding / file not loading (object not found)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I was trying to remove the `.php` extension and add a `/` as normal websites have. Example `http://example.com/category/`.

I use `.htaccess` to remove `.php`. Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# hide .php extension snippet
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

This code does its task. It removes `.php` and adds `/` but the PHP page is now not loading.

This is a screenshot (file name `test.php`):

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: If you temporarily remove your `.htaccess` file does `http://localhost/category/test.php` return the required response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few research that is actually working in my case is given below.

It removes the `.php` extension and adds `/` at the end of the URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference: https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: Does it redirect `http://localhost/category/test.php` to `http://localhost/category/test/` ?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. I have attached a screenshot and the reference. It is causing one issue (I have no idea how) when I use a relative path then I have to go one directory back. Example: To use a CSS file in the same folder I have to use `../style.css` URL.

Comment: One more thing to add I use `localhost/...` not `http://localhost/...`. Also `http://` is not hidden like in chrome it's actually not there it's just `localhost/...`. It may sound silly to you but I thought it may help you think better.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you're missing an internal rule to add `.php` silently to such redirect URIs.

You can add this rule in the end for that habndling:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# hide .php extension snippet
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,NE,L]

# add a trailing slash if needed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: @anubhawa solution seems not to be working. Check my new code: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# hide .php extension snippet
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]`

Comment: Can you try my updated answer now

Comment: I used the code in my question + added your new 2 lines below it, but the same issue. (I don't understand these codes well so I would be glad if you can provide me exact full code)

Comment: I've provided full .htaccess. Are you getting 404 for `localhost://category/test/`? Where does `test.php` exist? What is your `DocumentRoot` value?

Comment: I am on localhost (xampp server) with URL `http://localhost/category/test.php` => `http://localhost/category/test/`. But still output `Object not found!`. (Although appreciate your effort)

Comment: Please answer all the questions. What is your DocumentRoot value? Is category a real directory? Do you have more that one .htaccess? Where does this .htaccess located? Is there more code in this .htaccess?

Comment: DocumentRoot is `category` (root folder) in which `test.php` is a file. No other `.htaccess` file. The only `.htaccess` file is in `category` (root folder). No other code apart from given by you. Simply say: root folder name is `category` that has 2 files `test.php` and `.htaccess` which has not other code that given by you.

Comment: Wait, if category is `DocumentRoot` then your URL should be `http://localhost/test/` (without `category`).